# Glossaries "see" key, how to end with dot instead of comma?

Tags: glossaries

I am using "see" key with some entries of my glossary. Everything works fine, except that each entry that has "see" key automatically finishes with a comma, while I would like it to finish with a dot. I couldn't find how to change this in glossaries documentation. Does anybody know?

Here is my MWE main document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color}

%%% HYPERREFERENES %%%
\definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=webgreen}

%%% GLOSSARY %%%
\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
\glstoctrue
\makenoidxglossaries
\input{Glossary_mwe}

%%% DOCUMENT %%%
\begin{document}

\Gls{bowline_knot} is the most important knot for sailing. 

\Gls{fishermans_bend} (also known as \gls{anchor_bend}) is used to tie a rope to an anchor chain (or to an anchor directly) or to a buoy.

\printnoidxglossaries 

\end{document}
```

And here is the MWE glossary code:

```
\newglossaryentry{anchor_bend}{
    name={anchor bend},
    description={\nopostdesc},
    see=[\textnormal{See}]{fishermans_bend}
}

\newglossaryentry{bowline_knot}{
    name={bowline knot},
    description={A knot used to make a loop in the end of a rope. It is used to tie sheets and halyards to sails.}
}   

\newglossaryentry{fishermans_bend}{
    name={fisherman's bend},
    description={A knot used to tie a rope to an anchor chain (or to an anchor directly) or to a buoy.}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would really help if you could include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your question to demonstrate this. The comma usually only occurs after the "see" part if it's followed by one or more locations. If nothing follows the comma then it's likely that there's an invisible location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question by posting my MWE. As you can see, the "see" part is followed by a link (page number). Nevertheless, I would like the "see" part to end with a dot, because this is the case with all my other glossary entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with just the base `glossaries` package and `\makenoidxglossaries` then the simplest method is to remove the `see` key and place the cross-reference in the description:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color}

%%% HYPERREFERENES %%%
\definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=webgreen}

%%% GLOSSARY %%%
\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
\glstoctrue
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{anchor_bend}{
    name={anchor bend},
    description={See \glsseelist{fishermans_bend}.}
}

\newglossaryentry{bowline_knot}{
    name={bowline knot},
    description={A knot used to make a loop in the end of a rope. It is used to tie sheets and halyards to sails.}
}   

\newglossaryentry{fishermans_bend}{
    name={fisherman's bend},
    description={A knot used to tie a rope to an anchor chain (or to an anchor directly) or to a buoy.}
}

%%% DOCUMENT %%%
\begin{document}

\Gls{bowline_knot} is the most important knot for sailing. 

\Gls{fishermans_bend} (also known as \gls{anchor_bend}) is used to tie a rope to an anchor chain (or to an anchor directly) or to a buoy.

\printnoidxglossaries 

\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary with anchor bend See fisherman’s bend. 1]

The `\makenoidxglossaries` method is convenient in that you don't need to call an external tool, but [it's very inefficient](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml) and the page references can't be collated into ranges. If you're willing to try out another method, the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) package with [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) provides a better solution as it allows you to set up aliases.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you for your answer and additional advices!